# Powershell ForEach loop with embedded IF statements

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach

Starting to write powershell scripts (very new) because SCCM tends to respond better to them (both client and server)
So with the above stated here is my first script:

```
#Changes the 'ProvisioningMode' Key in the registry to False
$ProvisiongMode = New-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM\CcmExec -Name ProvisioningMode -Value False -Force
#Clears or 'nulls' the SystemTaskExcludes key in the registry
$SystemTaskExludes = New-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKLM\SOFTRWARE\Microsoft\CCM\CcmExec -Name SystemTaskExcludes - Value "" - Force
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$Success = "C:\Path\to.log"
$Failure = "C:\Path\to.log"
$Computers = Import-Csv "C:\Path\to.csv"
$SearchStr = Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM\CcmExec | select-object ProvisioningMode
$Online = Test-Conntection -Computername $ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet

ForEach ($ComputerName in $Computers)
if ($Online -eq 'False')
{
    Write-Output $ComputerName`t'Connection Failed'  >> $Failure
}
Else
{
    if ($SearchStr -eq True)
     {
        $ProvisioningMode
        $SystemTaskExcludes 
     }

}

#Second Check
if ($SearchStr -eq 'False')
{
    Write-Output $ComputerName`t'Registry has been changed' >> $Success
}
```

The issue in question is the `$Online` variable. I would like to see if a computer is responsive to ping, if true then proceed to run `$ProvisioningMode` and `$SystemTaskExclude`.
Then the other issue is querying that key to see if it changed. The issue with that one is `$SearchStr = Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM\CcmExec | select-object ProvisioningMode` returns

```
 ProvisionMode
 -----------------
 False
```

And I cant grab just the `false` data. 
Like I stated; very new at powershell and writing something that I will use helps me learn.

Edit: What I Have tried is

```
ForEach ($Name in $Computers) 
{
Test-Connection -BufferSize 2 -Computername $Name.ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet | Write-Output $Online
}

if ($Online -eq 'True') {Write-Output $Name`t'Computer is online' >> C:\Online.txt}
```

And many variations of the same thing.

```
 Test-Connection -BufferSize 2 -Computername $Name.ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet
```

Returns Data, which is what I want, but I need to input that into an `If` statement and still retain the `$Name` for the `$StringStr` and log files.

Those of you wondering, this takes the client out of provisioning mode when running an OSD. It fixes the 'No Self-Signed Certificate' issue.

Comment: Read the description of the "embedded"-tag

Comment: haha umm it was suppose to be 'embedded if statements'. My bad, Olaf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the string representations of boolean values in PowerShell are `True` and `False`, the correct way to compare againt such a value is with the `$true` and `$false` variables.

Furthermore, assign the result of `Test-Connection` to `$Online` with `=`:

```
$Online = Test-Connection -BufferSize 2 -Computername $Name.ComputerName -Count 1 -Quiet

if($Online -eq $true){
    # Machine responds to ping, do stuff!
}
```

But the comparison is actually unnecessary. If `$Online` already equals `$frue` or `$false`, you can use it on its own inside the if statement:

```
if($Online){
    # Machine responds to ping, do stuff!
}
```

---

I assume that `$ProvisionMode`, `$SystemTaskExcludes` and `$SearchStr` are all statements that you want to execute on the remote machine, not on the SCCM server itself.

To do so, you will need to connect to the machine and instruct it to execute the *-ItemProperty statements.

```
# Enclosing statements in {} creates a ScriptBlock - a piece of code that can be invoked later!
$ProvisionMode = { 
    #Changes the 'ProvisioningMode' Key in the registry to False
    New-ItemProperty  -Path Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM\CcmExec -Name ProvisioningMode -Value False -Force 
}

$SystemTaskExludes = { 
    #Clears or 'nulls' the SystemTaskExcludes key in the registry
    New-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKLM\SOFTRWARE\Microsoft\CCM\CcmExec -Name SystemTaskExcludes - Value "" - Force 
}

$SearchStr = { 
    Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CCM\CcmExec | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ProvisioningMode
}

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$LogFilePath = "C:\Path\to.log"

$Computers = Import-Csv "C:\Path\to.csv"


foreach($Computer in $Computers){

    $Online = Test-Connection -Computername $Computer.Name -Count 1 -Quiet

    if(-not $Online)
    {
        "$ComputerName`t'Connection Failed'" | Out-File -FilePath $LogFilePath -Append
    }
    else
    {
        $SearchResult = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer.Name -ScriptBlock $SearchStr
        if ($SearchResult)
        {
            # The call operator (&) invokes the scriptblock
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer.Name -ScriptBlock $ProvisionMode
            Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer.Name -ScriptBlock $SystemTaskExludes
        }
        else # SearchStr must be $false, or non-existing
        {
            "$ComputerName`t'Registry has been changed'" | Out-File -FilePath $LogFilePath -Append
        }
    }
}
```

For simplicity, I've used `Invoke-Command` with the `-ComputerName` parameter, but in a real world situation, I would set up a PSSession with `New-PSSession`, and reuse that for the connection with `Invoke-Command -Session`

Comment: So the script blocks allow for remote execution on the PCs (and yes, NOT the server), Oh and I see what you're doing with the `$SearchResult`. If its   true then run the blocks else do nothing (Intended result is 'False').

Took me a minute to decypher but I understand it now. That's a lot simpler than I expected. Thank you Mathias!!

Why did you opt for Out-File instead of Write-Output?

Comment: Write-Output is implied, and it also probably doesn't mean what you think. It doesn't write to a file or a variable, but takes one or more objects and sends them on through the pipeline

Comment: ScriptBlocks are just "portable code", you could have used `& $ProvisionMode` to invoke it locally as well, but yes, they are well suited for remote execution